# transitive closure in alloy

Tags: alloy

Can any one here explains how the transitive closure operator works in Alloy in terms of the matrix. I mean what's translation rule for translating closure operator into actual matrix operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compute transitive closure, Kodkod uses iterative squaring.

In a nutshell, if you have a binary relation `r` (which directly translates to a 2-dimensional boolean matrix), transitive closure of `r` can be computed iteratively as

- r<sub>1</sub> = r or (r . r)
- r<sub>2</sub> = r<sub>1</sub> or (r<sub>1</sub> . r<sub>1</sub>)
- r<sub>3</sub> = r<sub>1</sub> or (r<sub>2</sub> . r<sub>2</sub>)
- ...
- ^r = r<sub>n</sub> = r<sub>n-1</sub> or (r<sub>n-1</sub> . r<sub>n-1</sub>)

The question is when do we stop, i.e., what should `n` be.  Since everything is bounded, Kodkod statically knows the maximum number of rows in `r`, and it should be intuitively clear that if `n` is set to be that number of rows, the algorithm will produce a semantically correct translation.  However, even `n/2` is enough (since we are squaring the matrix every time), which is the actual number Kodkod uses.

Comment: One more question, if I have c^.contents, what's the input matrix for computing transitive closure ? Suppose c is a type of signature C. Then what's input matrix?

Comment: what I mean is if I say c in c^.contents, how you can make sure c will be present in a transitive closure matrix then?

Comment: `c` is irrelevant when computing the transitive closure of `contents`.  It is required that `contents` is a binary relation, then `^contents` is computed as I described previously, and finally a simple join between `c` and `^contents` is computed.

Comment: Actually, even a bound of  `ceiling(log_2(n))` is enough.